# How to remove Save and Refresh button in lightswitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

We are developing an ERP Product for a client. Need to remove Save and refresh buttons. I was able to disable them but couldn't remove. Can any one help me out to remove those buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way of handling this is just setting them as invisible per screen.
 Just open the screen in the designer, open the Screen Command Bar, select the button you don't want to appear and go to the properties, under Appearance, uncheck its "Is Visible" property. Then that button won't appear in the ribbon.